# RoR : Are devise controllers generated automatically or should we write on our own?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am new to ruby on rails. I am trying to use devise gem for authentication. i am going through the tutorials in github. I have created devise views using rails generate devise:views. But i dont find any controllers. Do i need to create on my own or is there any command to generate controllers for it?
Plz help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Devise already creates the required controllers for you behind the scenes. Few of these controllers are: `RegistrationController`, `SessionController`.

To customize or override any controller, say `RegistrationController`; you can do following (snippet from my one application):

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :admin_user, :only => [:destroy]

  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    if simple_captcha_valid? #verifying user registration by captcha
      super
    else
      build_resource
      clean_up_passwords(resource)
      flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error with the captcha code below. Please re-enter the code."      
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    # required for settings form to submit when password is left blank
    if params[:user][:password].blank?
      params[:user].delete("password")
      params[:user].delete("password_confirmation")
    end

    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      set_flash_message :notice, :updated
      # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case his password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy
    redirect_to rooth_path
  end
end
```

For more you can follow: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers

Comment: i dont find any controllers here. when are these controllers generated?

Comment: It is using Devise gem's controllers which exist in your gem configuration (and is installed in your application). You won't see them directly in your application's `app/controllers/`.